# 1 day older records from mysql

Tags: mysql

I store date as integer in my table

Now i wish to get all those records which are 1 day older

I use the following code. But it does not work

```
SELECT * from points where point_date < now() - interval 1 day
```

Comment: I wonder what could be wrong. Too bad that nobody knows _how_ exactly it does not work...

Comment: provide an example of date as integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function and see how it works.

```
SELECT * from points where FROM_UNIXTIME(point_date) < (now() - interval 1 day)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * from points where point_date < DATE_SUB(now() ,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```